# Table Creation on button click in c# windows forms app

Tags: c#, windows

Is there any way to create tables in database on button click with the value obtained from user input?
This is my code:

```
cmd.CommandText="CREATE TABLE '"+Input.Text+"'([Slno] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,[RefNo] VARCHAR(10)");
```

where `Input.Text` is the Textbox in which user input is captured.
The code points to an error.

Comment: What is error? Does exception thrown during runtime? Or maybe compiler prevent you write sql query with possible Sql injection?(that will be nice feature :))

Comment: With the actual error it's difficult to tell. Have you got a valid connection to your database? If you run the query directly against the database (using something like SQL management studio), is the database then created (you obviously replace the parameters with values)?

Comment: Im using local database .mdf and im doubted whether my connection  is stable. Im facing problems in starting Sql sever agent :(